# jquery count down timer with expiry callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using [keith-wood](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin to generate a count timer .
it works fine but when using the callback option i got issues

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

            function timerdone(){
                alert('welcome');
            }
                    $('#id').countdown({
                                 until: +300, 
                                 compact: true,
                                 onExpiry: timerdone,
                                 format: 'HMS'
                             });  
                })
```

for the above example it works with no problem but the issue when passing a variable to callback function the page call function once it loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
                function timerdone(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
                        $('#id').countdown({
                                     until: +300, 
                                     compact: true,
                                     onExpiry: timerdone('welcome'),
                                     format: 'HMS'
                                 });  
                    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onExpiry: function() {
    timerdone('welcome');
},
```

Instead of invoking your function, pass it as a reference by using an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Brad M's answer--

You're making a relatively common mistake in JS--instead of passing a reference to a function, you're invoking it and passing its return value.

Eg

```
// in the following, onExpiry is expecting a function reference 
// (also called a function handle). The function will be invoked
// later on.

...
onExpiry: timerdone,
// this worked fine, you were passing a reference to the function

onExpiry: timerdone(), 
// this MISTAKE is something many people do. It is invoking the function (with
// no arguments) and then sending the function's return value for <onExpiry>

onExpiry: timerdone('welcome'),
// this was your MISTAKE. Same as above, you're invoking the function instead
// of sending the function reference as is expected. You're invoking
// the function with 1 argument, but the argument isn't the issue. The issue
// is that you're invoking the function and sending its result (return
// value) as <onExpiry> 
// 
// There are different ways to fix it, @Brad's solution is a good one.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = $('#counter');

var due = new Date();
due.setHours(due.getHours()+24);
due.setSeconds(due.getSeconds() + 3);

var dueMinus24Hours = new Date(due);
dueMinus24Hours.setHours(due.getHours()-24);

var timeout = dueMinus24Hours-new Date();

setTimeout(function() {
    counter.countdown('option', { format: 'HMS' });
}, timeout);

counter.countdown({
        until: due,
        format: 'OD',
        padZeroes: true
    });
```